# Recover Firefox tabs when closing main window with "organize bookmarks" open

Tags: firefox, tabs

I have Firefox 3.0 (under Win XP) configured to show tabs from previous sessions when starting and automatically save the session when exiting. Firefox even offers to restore tabs after a crash. I keep a large workspace of open tabs, and because the recovery is usually so effective, I don't think about frequently saving the open tab set as a bookmark.

There is one situation that seems to irrecoverably lose all the tabs, though. That is when I close the main Firefox window (intending to close Firefox entirely) while the "organize bookmarks" window is open. This happens more often that I would like, since it is easy to forget about the "organize bookmarks" window if it is minimized.

When opening Firefox's main window again, all the tabs are gone. And the "recently closed tabs" history is cleared.

I know Firefox must be saving the tab list somewhere to make the crash recovery possible. Is there any way to access it in this case?  I suppose I could use task manager to kill Firefox and initiate the crash recovery (if I happen to notice the bookmarks window before trying to re-open Firefox) but is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are the session restore APIs that you could use.  However, there is "Undo Close Window" in Firefox 3.5 (which has been out for some time now) that would also solve your problem.